# C# execute a terminal command in linux

Tags: c#, linux, bash, terminal

I want my c# application (which I execute on a raspberry pi) to run a bash script whenever it starts..
basically : the script is located in `/etc/init.d` and is named `mnw`. I want whenever my c# application starts, it should execute a part of the mnw script.
If it was written it in the terminal would look like :

```
cd /etc/init.d
./mnw stop
```

I want this to happen right at the start of `public static void Main()`, I've been trying

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo() { FileName = "/dev/init.d/./mnw", Arguments = "stop", }; 
Process proc = new Process() { StartInfo = startInfo, };
proc.Start();
```

but it says that stop is a unexpected argument, any ideas?

Comment: One obvious error - `FileName = "/dev/init.d/./mnw"` should have been `FileName = "/etc/init.d/mnw"`, but I assume that it's a typo while pasting in this question.

Comment: why not create bash script instead ?

Comment: this is mnw 
if [ "$1" = "start" ]
then
        start-stop-daemon --start --background -m --oknodo --pidfile /home/pi/p$
elif [ "$1" = "startnbg" ]
then
        start-stop-daemon --start -m --oknodo --pidfile /home/pi/pid/MonoDaemon$

elif [ "$1" = "stop" ]
then
        start-stop-daemon --stop --retry=TERM/30/KILL/5 --pidfile /home/pi/pid/$
else
        echo Unknown command
fi

Comment: No need of argument `ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo() { FileName = "/etc/init.d/mnw stop"};` **or try**
`ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo() { FileName = "/bin/bash", Arguments = "/etc/init.d/mnw stop", };`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have never used `ProcessStartInfo` on Mono / Linux, but have you tried calling via bash?

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo() { FileName = "/bin/bash", Arguments = "/dev/init.d/mnw stop", }; 
Process proc = new Process() { StartInfo = startInfo, };
proc.Start();
```

Also, there is no issues with the executable bit on `mnw`?

Comment: comment says the same :)

Comment: Ah, totally missed, that, started writing like an hour ago and forgot to press `add`:)

Answer (score 11):

While using the `Process` class like in the accepted answer works, I'
d like to add that there is a library called [CliWrap](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CliWrap) that makes CLI calls like this much easier:

- fluent API to build the calls
- async support
- call with custom environment variables
- set working directory
- ability to pipe stdout/stderr into a string
- retrieve exit code
- etc.

using OPs question as example:

```
var result = await Cli
                  .Wrap("/dev/init.d/mnw")
                  .WithArguments("stop")
                  .ExecuteBufferedAsync();

// result contains:
// -- result.StandardOutput  (string)
// -- result.StandardError   (string)
// -- result.ExitCode        (int)
// -- result.StartTime       (DateTimeOffset)
// -- result.ExitTime        (DateTimeOffset)
// -- result.RunTime         (TimeSpan)

if (result.ExitCode != 0)
    Console.WriteLine("Command failed")
```

Thank you [@Tyrrrz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2205454/tyrrrz) for this library!