# WMI set variable in LINUX?

Tags: linux, vb.net, windows, wmi

What is in Linux the equivalent code of this vb.net snipplet:

```
    Public Sub SwitchGFX() 
' Switches GFX card on MSI Notebooks
' Coded by Zibri http://www.zibri.org
        Dim mo As New ManagementObject("\root\WMI:MSI_System.InstanceName=""ACPI\\PNP0C14\\0_4""")
        mo.SetPropertyValue("System", 1)
        mo.Put()
    End Sub
```

Or this windows shell command:

```
wmic /namespace:\\root\wmi path MSI_System.InstanceName="ACPI\\PNP0C14\\0_4" set System=0
wmic /namespace:\\root\wmi path MSI_System.InstanceName="ACPI\\PNP0C14\\0_4" set System=1
```

P.S.
This code switches the VGA from Intel to NVIDIA on a MSI Notebook.

Answer (score -1):

WMI will most likely not work on Linux as it requires Windows's WMI service. However, [this article](https://www.linuxbabe.com/desktop-linux/switch-intel-nvidia-graphics-card-ubuntu) mentions how you can switch to another GPU via a terminal command (see the bottom of Step 4). So combined [with some research](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23681651/3740093) in how you can run Linux terminal commands from .NET (the answer appears to be Bash, by the way), I suppose this could be a potential solution:

```
Public Sub SwitchToNVIDIA()
    Process.Start("/bin/bash", "prime-select nvidia")
End Sub

Public Sub SwitchToIntel()
    Process.Start("/bin/bash", "prime-select intel")
End Sub
```

Comment: Nope. I can switch graphic card using wmi in WINDOWS (I reversed MSI utility and understood how to do it). I need to to the same in linux and YES: there is a way to access wmi from linux.. look at fwts. What you posted is a dot.net program that runs bash.. I am ON LINUX.

Comment: @Zibri : Of course it's a .NET program! Isn't that what you asked for? You can run .NET applications on Linux via Mono!

Comment: Linux is not a programming language, so what language do you want it in then? If it wasn't VB.NET you wanted then your question is very unclear.

Comment: @Zibri : And why do you so badly want it to be WMI? Is there anything wrong with those two short bash commands?

Comment: I will be more clear: that article does not apply to my laptop. prime-select does not work. It switched the videocard in a proprietary way. To do so it uses mapped bios entries in WMI... on windows I have no problems do it programatically because I reversed their software and understood how to do it. On linux there is no way at the moment. The only way would be to use WMI (mapped in linux!) or a direct bios nvram write (which I will probably do). This has nothing to do with VB NET or MONO. Because even having the full .NET on linux, we would not have that WMI entry mapped.

Comment: @Zibri : Well it was worth a shot. Since I've never used Linux I'm afraid I can't do much more than what I can find on the internet.

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind. I reversed the MSI software and replicated the switch on Linux and in efi shell.
Now windows is not needed anymore to switch graphic cards.

I will post everything on my website http://www.zibri.org